# Custom allocator: Valgrind shows 7 allocs, 0 frees, no leaks

Tags: c, memory-management, valgrind

I am working on a clone of the `malloc (3)` functions (`malloc`, `realloc` and `free` for now).

I would like to add support for Valgrind. I'm using [these docs](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.mempools). However, after adding calls to the `VALGRIND_MEMPOOL_FREE`, `VALGRIND_MEMPOOL_ALLOC` and `VALGRIND_CREATE_MEMPOOL` macros, I get the following from Valgrind:

```
==22303== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22303==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22303==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 0 frees, 2,039 bytes allocated
==22303== 
==22303== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
```

This is despite my [`realloc` calling `VALGRIND_MEMPOOL_FREE`](https://github.com/conradkleinespel/malloc-c/blob/90b1f26ff5ceca872ba41e8ca3bde351c286d6aa/ft_realloc.c) and my [`free` calling `VALGRIND_MEMPOOL_FREE`](https://github.com/conradkleinespel/malloc-c/blob/90b1f26ff5ceca872ba41e8ca3bde351c286d6aa/ft_free.c).

What could be the cause of this ?

Comment: See [http://valgrind.10908.n7.nabble.com/VALGRIND-MEMPOOL-FREE-not-reflected-in-heap-summary-td42789.html](http://valgrind.10908.n7.nabble.com/VALGRIND-MEMPOOL-FREE-not-reflected-in-heap-summary-td42789.html) and [https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=233298](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=233298).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What could be the cause of this ?

This is due to a bug in valgrind. See the [link](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=233298) to the valgrind bug tracker in my comment to your answer.

From the other [link](http://valgrind.10908.n7.nabble.com/VALGRIND-MEMPOOL-FREE-not-reflected-in-heap-summary-td42789.html) in my comment:

> A cursory search through the source code indicates that MEMPOOL_ALLOC
>   calls new_block, which increments cmalloc_n_mallocs, but there is no
>   corresponding change to cmalloc_n_frees in MEMPOOL_FREE.

```
/* valgrind.c */
#include <valgrind/valgrind.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char pool[100];

    VALGRIND_CREATE_MEMPOOL(pool, 0, 0);
    VALGRIND_MEMPOOL_ALLOC(pool, pool, 8);
    VALGRIND_MEMPOOL_FREE(pool, pool);
    VALGRIND_DESTROY_MEMPOOL(pool);
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc valgrind.c -g
$ valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all ./a.out
==10186== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==10186== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10186== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10186== Command: ./a.out
==10186== 
==10186== 
==10186== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10186==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10186==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 8 bytes allocated
==10186== 
==10186== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==10186== 
==10186== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10186== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
$
```

Comment: This is interesting, thank you for the hint! Though I'm not sure if it's actually the issue. I see the `cmalloc_n_frees` variable being incremented in 3.10, which is the version I am on (the version from the bug report are 3.5 and 3.6). `cmalloc_n_frees` is incremented in `memcheck/mc_malloc_wrappers.c` at lines 479/522 (source: http://valgrind.org/downloads/current.html). Also, I'm a little skeptical as to how the Valgrind dev team could have missed such an obvious bug. After all, the standard `malloc` reports just fine with Valgrind. I am not using `DESTROY_MEMPOOL` atm. Is it required ?

Comment: @conradk The relevant function is `mempool_free` in line 861 where the `cmalloc_n_frees` is not incremented. `mempool_alloc` in line 832 calls `new_block` where the `cmalloc_n_mallocs` is incremented, but `mempool_free` doesn't call `handle_free` where `cmalloc_n_frees` would have been incremented. The valgrind dev team did not miss the bug. It is in their bug tracker, but it is strange it is not yet fixed after such a long time (more than five years).

Comment: @conradk `VALGRIND_DESTROY_MEMPOOL` doesn't change anything in the output. I added an example with it.

Comment: Ah OK, Valgrind uses the KDE bug tracking system, I didn't get that before. Thanks for the explanations regarding DESTROY_MEMPOOL ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from here: http://valgrind.10908.n7.nabble.com/VALGRIND-MEMPOOL-FREE-not-reflected-in-heap-summary-td42789.html

> A cursory search through the source code indicates that MEMPOOL_ALLOC 
>   calls new_block, which increments cmalloc_n_mallocs, but there is no 
>   corresponding change to cmalloc_n_frees in MEMPOOL_FREE. Here's a 
>   patch that increments it at the very end of MEMPOOL_FREE. This gives 
>   me the behavior I expect.

Comment: `Here's a patch` Where?

Comment: IF you copypaste from other sources you are expected to mark this text as being a citation!